# FontAwesomeIcon with Nuxt 3 raises two lint errors in my code

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, font-awesome

I am using Nuxt 3 and want to have fontawesome. It actually works, but I have some lint errors that I am not getting rid of and I want to understand if I did something wrong or not.

Here's part of the content of my `package.json`, in case you are wondering if I have the needed packages, among others:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.3.8",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "nuxt": "^3.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.5",
    ...
}
```

Then, my `nuxt.config.ts` has, among other things:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: [
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css',
  ],
})
```

I have a file `plugins/fontawesome.ts` on my Nuxt 3 installation that contains:

```
import { library, config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faLink } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

config.autoAddCss = false

library.add(faLink)

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('FontAwesomeIcon', FontAwesomeIcon, {})
})
```

Now, the two annoying erros I get from lint are:

```
ESLint: FontAwesomeIcon not found in '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome' (import/named)
TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
```

The first one is related to the import at the top of my `plugins/fontawesome.ts` file, and the second one is related to the `defineNuxtPlugin`, and it is complaining about the `{}` at the end of `nuxtApp.vueApp.component('FontAwesomeIcon', FontAwesomeIcon, {})`

If you are curious about my lint configuration, here it is `.eslintrc.cjs`:

```
module.exports = {
    extends: [
        '@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript'
    ],
    rules: {
        'comma-dangle': ['error', 'only-multiline'],
    }
}
```

The interesting thing with all of this, is that the icon does display on the page of my nuxt 3 app, but the errors of lint keep making noise, and I don't understand why. Has anyone gotten similar results?